# How do I revert a probability distribution back to its source data samples?

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, density-function, generative-models

Normally we first collect real samples into a dataset and describe its probability  distribution parametrically or empirically.

If I instead generate a parametric distribution for artificial data first,

(for example, in python with `scipy.stats.dist.pdf(x)`, where `dist` could be Guassian, Gumbel, etc, although this is not restricted to a coding question),

how do I revert back to the actual samples used to simulate that distribution?

Comment: What do you mean to "reverting back" and to what samples? If you create artificial data, than there is no real samples, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: but i didn't create the artificial data. I created an artificial distribution. In the real world approach, we collect data first *and then* see how it is distributed. In other words, the data came before the distribution. Therefore, I would think that the artificial distribution must have likewise came from artificial data, even though I didn't start out with the data. I started out with the distribution. given that in the real world it is easy to go from *data to the distribution*, the question here is how to go *backwards* from *distribution to the data*

Answer (score 4):

> In the real world approach, we collect data first *and then* see how it
> is distributed. In other words, the data came before the distribution.
> Therefore, I would think that the artificial distribution must have
> likewise came from artificial data, even though I didn't start out
> with the data. I started out with the distribution. given that in the
> real world it is easy to go from *data to the distribution*, the
> question here is how to go *backwards from distribution* to the data.

Probability distribution and random variable are abstract concepts. They do not exist in real world. We use them to *approximate* the things we observe in real world. For example, we choose to use Gaussian distribution to describe how some data is distributed. This does not mean that the data "comes" from Gaussian distribution, rather that we use it to approximate how the data is distributed.

You could use the data to estimate parameters needed to find the best fit of some distribution to the data. There is no going "backwards". The only "backwards" step is to generate random samples from the distribution (the `.rvs()` methods in scipy), however those are not samples that "lead" to this distribution. More than this, if you generate samples from the distribution, it does not have to be the case that after fitting distribution to those samples, after fitting the distribution to them, you would recover exactly the same parameters as were used for generating the samples (you should, as the number of samples increases), because they are *random*.